# Merging multiple data frames using only a loop in R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I have multiple data sets, which are returned by function `return_page(page)`, where 'page' indicates the page number respectively. Each data set has the same number of rows and columns, and they also have same names for each page.
I need to merge 5 pages to create a single data frame using only FOR loop. So far, I have done it using the following function:

`data <- rbind(return_page(1),return_page(2),return_page(3),return_page(4),return_page(5))`

Yet, it doesn't meet my needs, since it isn't a loop and uses hard-coding. Please, let me know how can I accomplish this task using a loop.

Comment: Just o little note: R is a vectorized language, you usually want to avoid using for loop. See more [here](https://swcarpentry.github.io/r-novice-gapminder/09-vectorization/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
df <- return_page(1)

for (i in 2:5) {
  df <- rbind(df, return_page(i))
}
```

Comment: I've just tried this and it worked! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You could use an apply or map function here:

```
library(purrr)

map(1:5, return_page)%>%rbind.data.frame(.)
```

For a solution limited to a for loop, see the answer by @Soldalma below

Comment: Thank you for the reply! But is it possible to do this as a loop (because I am required to do this exactly as FOR or WHILE loop)?